# Making a Dart package with localization needs

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a made a utility class I think would fit into a package. I use some localized words inside and currently I inject them at constructor level. This way my package is independent of how the user of the package implements localization. The package is able to translate date and time into some specific texts and some of the localized words are like "tomorrow", yesterday and so on. 
I'm wondering if there could be another way to support localization in a package I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

I use a plugin called EasyLocalization https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization
Define json file and it loads it for you.

```
{
  "title": "Hello",
  "msg": "Hello {} in the {} world ",
  "clickMe": "Click me",
  "profile": {
    "reset_password": {
      "title": "Reset Password",
      "username": "Username",
      "password": "password"
    }
  },
  "clicked": {
    "zero": "You clicked {} times!",
    "one": "You clicked {} time!",
    "other": "You clicked {} times!"
  }
}
```